# Antithetic Variates - Variance Reduction

Tags: probability, monte-carlo

In Glasserman's "Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering", page 208, he states the following regarding antithetic variates:

> Suppose that $Y = f(Z)$ with $Z = (Z_1,\ldots,Z_d) \sim N(0,I)$.  Define the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of $f$, respectively, by
>   $$
> f_0(z) = \frac{f(z) + f(-z)}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f_1(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(-z)}{2}.
> $$
>   Clearly, $f = f_0 + f_1$, and [after showing this gives an orthogonal decomposition of f]
>   $$
> \text{Var}[f(Z)] = \text{Var}[f_0(Z)] + \text{Var}[f_1(Z)]
> $$
>   The first term on the right is the variance of an estimate of $E(f(Z))$ based on an antithetic pair $(Z, -Z)$. Thus, **antithetic sampling eliminates all variance if $f$ is antisymmetric ($f = f_1$) and it eliminates no variance if $f$ is symmetric ($f = f_0$)**

(Boldface mine). I can see why antithetic variates would eliminate all variance **in the estimator** if $f$ is antisymmetric---the estimator is constantly zero---but I don't see the point of this orthogonal variance decomposition to see this, and I'm afraid I'm missing something important. My question is, what is the point of this variance decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

The book is indeed slightly amiss in spelling out the connection. The point is that $\mathbf E[f_0]$ is the estimator of $\mathbf E[f]$ and what we are calculating. From Equation (1), we see that the estimator has a lower variance
$$\text{Var}[f_0(Z)]\le\text{Var}[f(Z)]$$
and the inequality is strict when $f$ is not symmetric.